# in Expression engine form Admin section there is option of validating "Is this a required field?"

Tags: validation

in Expression engine form Admin section there is option of validating "Is this a required field?". doing the check box also it the validation is not working. please any body help me as soon as possible

it already there in admin section saying "Is this a required field?", i checked the check box and submit it. but still the validation is not happening.
 location of page is CP>Home>Administration>Custom Channel> Fields>Edit Field

Field Type is Matrix. Matrix Configuration is file type

Comment: Could you please try to explain a bit more about what your problem is? Are you trying to edit an entry, and are the required fields not being required? Or do you want to do additional validation? Or is this about a module?

Comment: You seem to have created two separate accounts. To keep your rep and questions under one account, please merge your accounts as detailed here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 5):

If your field is a Matrix field, just checking the native "Is this a required field?" is not sufficient. You need to look further down in your Matrix columns. There is an "Is col required" setting for each column in your matrix field. Tick those and presto, required columns in a matrix field.

You can also constrain the number of rows by using the min rows and max rows parameters